# Magnet not redirecting on uTorrent

Tags: vlc-media-player, bittorrent, utorrent, magnet, magnet-links

On downloading VLC Torrent Streamer, the torrent magnets now get redirected to VLC, and I am unable to change it back to uTorrent. I tried deleting the magnet-redirect plugin that got installed in VLC, as well as changing the default locations on regedit and default application settings. However, I still get the same message as shown in this image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to your downloads folder, right click the .torrent file and choose "Open with". uTorrent will be an option.

If not, keep clicking choose another program and find the .exe of uTorrent.

There's also an option in Firefox to manually configure a default application for a given file type.

If none of these work, use Revo Uninstaller to uninstall both VLC and uTorrent and start again.

Comment: The question is about magnet links,  not  torrent files.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the link of the torrent magnet file, then paste it in torrent, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox's latest version (v71- 32bit) I was able to fix this behaviour (when my magnet links started opening in VLC player. And it started to happen when I installed Acrobat Pro11 btw) by just going to FF options> General Tab and in their list of applications, I found 'Magnet Links' and parallel to it I chose 'Utorrent'.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for this, as seen in the screenshot below:

[image: Preferences - General]